# Difference between (Clojure's) multimethod and (C#'s) extension methods?

Tags: c#, clojure

I just watched a video on protocols in Clojure and it explained how 'multimethods' work. It seems to me that they look very similar to how extension methods in C# work. Are they basically the same thing (with the exception that you don't need to create a static class in Clojure) or is there a fundamental difference? Is there an advantage or disadvantage in using either?

Comment: +1 for another language again I've never listened before

Comment: For your information, C# extension methods might better fit the Clojure concept of extending a type with a protocol. Have a look at the `extend-type` function. Multimethods are much more powerful but comes with a price, that is performance.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The mutlimethod feature in Clojure is for multiple dispatch scenarios. It effectively enables runtime polymorphism where the method that is invoked depends on the type of the **arguments** to the method (traditional single-dispatch polymorphism depends on the runtime type of the object receiving the method call). Basically, you can think of single-dispatch polymorphism as a method `M`

```
M(arg1, arg2, arg3, ..., argn)
```

and the actual method that is invoked depends on the runtime type of `arg1` (so we're rewriting the usual syntax of

```
arg1.M(arg2, arg3, ..., argn)
```

as

```
M(arg1, arg2, arg3, ..., argn)
```

to make the analogy clear. In multiple dispatch, the method that is invoked by

```
M(arg1, arg2, arg3, ..., argn)
```

depends on the runtime types of `arg1`, `arg2`, ..., `argn` as well.

You can [achieve](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/laurionb/archive/2009/08/13/multimethods-in-c-4-0-with-dynamic.aspx) similar functionality in C# with `dynamic`.

Frankly, it's not related to extension methods at all.

Comment: +1 for answer about another language that I've never listened before :)

Comment: This is write but I have to add a note that multimethodes in clojure are not restricted to dispatch on type. Type however is used for dispatch. In clojure you could for example write a method that depends on the type of the first and the second argument and then if the third argument is bigger then then call one method or else the other. Its compliantly arbitrary. Read this for more information and some more features multimethods have in Clojure. http://clojure.org/multimethods

Answer (score 4):

Clojure multimethods are designed for **fully dynamic dispatch** - i.e. you can select the implementation of a function on the basis of an **arbitrary** function over the parameters.

An example of dispatching on a calculated property:

```
(def stone {:name "stone" :weight 1000})

(def feather {:name "feather" :weight 1})

;; dispatch function - can be any function
(defn heaviness [thing]
  (if (> (:weight thing) 100)
    "Heavy"
    "Not heavy"))

;; multimethod definition using the given dispatch function
(defmulti lift heaviness)

;; implementation of two alternative methods based
(defmethod lift "Heavy" 
  (fn [thing] 
    (str "Trying to lift a heavy " (:name thing))))

(defmethod lift "Not heavy" 
  (fn [thing] 
    (str "Easily lifting a light " (:name thing))))

(lift stone)
=> "Trying to lift a heavy stone"

(lift feather)
=> "Easily lifting a light feather"
```